Custom controls disappear after entering Fullscreen on react video
So I tried adding a skip button to my video container in react, it works however for some reason it dissapears in fullscreen?
return (
    <div className="video-section">
      <div
        className="video-container"
        onMouseEnter={() => setShowArrows(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setShowArrows(false)}
        onTouchStart={handleTouch}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      >
        {showStatic ? (
          <ReactPlayer
            url={staticEffectVideo}
            playing
            className="video-section-player"
            width="90vw"
            height="90vh"
          />
        ) : (
          videoUrls.length > 0 && (
            <ReactPlayer
              url={videoUrls[currentIndex]}
              playing={userHasInteracted}
              className="video-section-player"
              onEnded={goToNextVideo}
              controls
              width="90vw"
              height="90vh"
            />
          )
        )}
        <div
          className="BackArrow"
          style={{ opacity: showArrows ? 1 : 0 }}
          onClick={goToPreviousVideo}
        >
          <IoPlaySkipBackSharp />
        </div>
        <div
          className="ForwardArrow"
          style={{ opacity: showArrows ? 1 : 0 }}
          onClick={goToNextVideo}
        >
          <IoPlaySkipForward />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

I have no idea why this isn't working.. here's the css:
.video-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
  position: relative;
}

.video-section-player {
  width: 85vw;
  height: 85vh;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transitions for effects */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #c5a365; /* Added a solid border */
  z-index: 10; /* Lower z-index means it will be behind elements with a higher z-index */
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(255, 233, 234, 0.7),
    0 0 16px rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.5), 0 0 24px rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.3),
    0 0 32px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* Intensify neon shadow with multiple layers */
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
}

.BackArrow,
.ForwardArrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 20; /* Ensure it's on top of the video player */
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transitions */
  opacity: 0; /* Initially hidden */
}

Can someone help me, this is really weird? the controls are working perfectly fine but they completely dissapear upon entering fullscreen..
